# MultivalueMap to return byte[] array in Spring Rest API

Tags: java, spring, rest, multipart

My requirement is to get a list of bytes[] in one rest call using Spring Rest API. So, for this i use **MultiValueMap** in Spring Rest as my rest response. My Controller method looks like this :

```
@ResponseBody
@RequestMapping(value = "/download/{fileIds}", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public MultiValueMap<String, byte[]> downloadManuals(
        @PathVariable String cmmIds) {
    byte[] fileBinaryData = null;

    MultiValueMap<String, byte[]> multiPartData = new LinkedMultiValueMap<>();

    for(String fileId : fileIds.split(",")){            
        fileBinaryData = new byte[10];//Logic for creating a data here
        multiPartData.add(fileId, fileBinaryData);
    }
    return multiPartData;
}
```

Problem : While calling this rest service, it is throwing an exception :

**java.lang.ClassCastException: [B cannot be cast to java.lang.String**

Its throwing this error because there is no proper convertor for byte[] array.So by default its tryting to convert in to string which cause ClassCastException.

Does anybody know a proper convortor for this.I searched in internet but unable to achiece this. I ***tried same using jersey*** and achieve exact soluation using **MultiPart** provided by it which is having a convortor for it. I wanted to achieve same using spring rest.

Comment: I'm not using spring, but default serialization for binary data over http is Base64 Hex Encoded. This is normaly the default. But I think that is not your problem. Your problem is that you forgot to define the generics for LinkedMultiValueMap<String, byte[]>, because in the Exception is shown the generic  Placeholder B.

Comment: And a generic on simple type byte[] looks strange for me. Propably you need a wrapper Object for your byte[].

Comment: Thanks for your reply Rena. [B is the class name for Byte array.So, exception clear says its not able to convert from Byte array to String as it require some converters in Spring.